# Magento get current page title by store id or store code

Tags: php, magento, segment-io

Is there any way to get current page title by store code or id?

The following code gives the current page title but is of currently selected store view eg http://example.com/it/shop.html which is Italian store view.

The context is ~/Model/Controller/Page.php

`$title = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('head')->getTitle();`

I am trying to figure out way to get current page title by specific store code like `en` or `it` or id. This is for always forcing the Segment.io analytics `page` call to English text.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried below code??

```
  $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load('Page-Identifier');

    $pageTitle = $page->getTitle();
```

Comment: Nope, doesnt work. First, for this we need to pass the current page identifier. Second, it will work only in case of CMS pages if we find current page identifier and not for pages like product catalog and contact.

Comment: If you need for catalog and product page then you should create the observer. This might help you -->http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71037/change-dynamic-title-of-review-page/71047#71047

Comment: Updated the question, please refer.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a PHTML file I think you can only translate string like this:

```
$this->__($this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle())
```

If you want to use store view translation you should `setTitle` somewhere in the block class or controller.

Comment: The context is ~/Model/Controller/Page.php

Current code:
`$title = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('head')->getTitle();`

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not that easy. The title could have been set anywhere, and it is set as localized string without any additional information.

### Examples

#### Category page

The title is set within the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View` block

```
if ($headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
    $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    if ($title = $category->getMetaTitle()) {
        $headBlock->setTitle($title);
    }
```

#### Product page

The title is set within the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` block

```
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
if ($headBlock) {
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
    if ($title) {
        $headBlock->setTitle($title);
    }
```

#### CMS page

The title is set within the `Mage_Cms_Block_Page` block

```
$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
if ($head) {
    $head->setTitle($page->getTitle());
```

#### Cart

The title is set within the `Mage_Checkout_CartController` (not a block this time!)

```
$this
    ->loadLayout()
    ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
    ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')
    ->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Shopping Cart'));
```

*and so on, and so on*

**Unfortunately there is no single point to hook in, you would have to handle all cases separately.**

The only common method is `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::setTitle()` and as stated before, this is too late because it already gets the localized string.

Also, as you can see in the examples, sometimes the title is a translated text with `__()` and sometimes it is an attribute of a model in the context of the current store view.

Comment: Updated the question, please refer.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are trying to get the information, it is not there